# sudo：rosdep: command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone!

I'm installing ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and following the instructions on this website: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

After step 1.4, I run $ sudo rosdep init, it says "sudo: rosdep: command not found". I think I've downloaded python-rosdep pack.
Here's what I did:

```
~$ locate rosdep
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdep_0.11.4-1_all.deb

~$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives
    /var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo rosdep init
sudo：rosdep: command not found
```

Did I miss any step? Or did I do something wrong?

Thanks! Any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225394/sudo%EF%BC%9Arosdep:-command-not-found/) by [MIchael9792](https://answers.ros.org/users/25783/michael9792/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How you installed `rosdep` is the question. Did you follow http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep#Installing_rosdep that says using `apt-get`?

```
~$ locate rosdep
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdep_0.11.4-1_all.deb
```

That just means you somehow downloaded an installer and doesn't necessarily mean it's installed.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIchael9792](https://answers.ros.org/users/25783/michael9792/) on 2016-01-29**:
Thank you! I truly didn't install rosdep, just downloaded it. Great thanks!